# Access AWS Node SDK inside firewall without changing any configuration in firewall

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, firewall

I have a desktop app which downloads app assets after installation is completed.
App uses **aws node sdk** to download all the assets from **S3 buckets**.
Problem comes when app is getting installed inside company firewall. Company firewall blocks the api request used by aws node sdk.
And I can't ask all my client to white-list amazon web service urls but I can ask them to white-list my own company url like ***.mycompany.com**.
Is there any way we can access **aws node sdk** using my company domain.

Comment: Can you make the assets public?

Comment: There are a number of potential solutions, but selecting one requires a more thorough understanding of two things: 1. Why do you need the Node SDK rather than simply any HTTP client?  Are your assets protected? If so, how does the application obtain its credentials?   2. Are you certain your clients can allow access by hostname?  That is probably the exception, not the rule.  External network access from within corporate networks often relies on known, fixed, external IP addresses, not hostnames.  A typical firewall can't determine the hostname from an HTTPS request -- they're encrypted.

Comment: We can't make it public these are licences-ed contents.

Comment: We can't make it public these are licences-ed contents. 1. These are not public assets and we also want app to work in offline mode after downloading assets.Yes our assets is protected. App obtains S3 credential by making an api call to our server(*.example.com) 2. Yes we are sure. We already have other app using *.example.com which works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had this same problem and resolved it by creating a proxy API endpoint on a separate server that would take the request, and pipe the stream from AWS S3 back to the client. Because this proxy endpoint was hosted in a whitelisted domain, we didn't have to worry about the company's firewall blocking the request.

Comment: Thanks buddy. I have tried the same it works very well. I want to invite you to my league game just in case if u want to play :)